# A JSONObject text must begin with '{'

Tags: java, json

I have a '{' at the beginning, here is my json file

```
{
    "Rooms": [
        {"x":1},
        {"y":1}
    ]
}
```

Maybe it can't read the file?
Here's my code:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener("res/MAP.JSON");
JSONObject test = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

Comment: Show us the actual, complete error message, with stack trace and everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener("res/MAP.JSON");
```

This doesn't read from the file `res/MAP.JSON`. This tries to tokenize the string `"res/MAP.JSON"` as JSON. Since that string isn't JSON, it doesn't work.

If you want to read from a file, try passing in a `java.io.FileReader`:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(new FileReader("res/MAP.JSON"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html

"A JSONTokener takes a source string and extracts characters and tokens from it. It is used by the JSONObject and JSONArray constructors to parse JSON source strings."

`JSONTokener` doesn't read the file for you. It simply tokenizes the string you supply.

There is something wrong with the JSON you are supplying.

Use `JsonLint` to validate your JSON: http://www.jsonlint.com

It'd help to see contents of MAP.JSON.